# Resource (.resx) file Key naming conventions?

Tags: c#, resources, naming-conventions, translation

I'm building a C# app that will likely contain a couple resource files to store strings for use in language translation. I'm trying to come up with a naming convention for the Keys in my resouce files. Has anyone tackled this before me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use Pascal naming convention. Dont attribute the key to a module or the class. Generalize it so that it can be reused.

Eg: ReadWriteWarningMessage

The dot separated convention works fine for menu items. But what about strings that are generated dynamically or user messages.

Answer (score 6):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-resources.  As @bobbyalex has said, this includes using PascalCasing, since the generated resource designer file does implement the resources as properties.

> ✔️ DO use PascalCasing in resource keys.
>
> ✔️ DO provide descriptive rather than short identifiers.
>
> ❌ DO NOT use language-specific keywords of the main CLR languages.
>
> ✔️ DO use only alphanumeric characters and underscores in naming resources.
>
> ✔️ DO use the following naming convention for exception message resources.
>
> The resource identifier should be the exception type name plus a short identifier of the exception:
>
> `ArgumentExceptionIllegalCharacters` `ArgumentExceptionInvalidName` `ArgumentExceptionFileNameIsMalformed`

Answer (score 5):

have you considered underscores like Menu_File_Open or something like Place_StringDescription?
I currently employ a scheme where common stuff go to Common_ like Common_PressHereTo and view specific go to their respective place like MainMenu_FileOpen. In general, before the underscore i type where the Resource appears and after the underscore a descriptive text.

Answer (score 4):

I try to organize it similar to the namespaces I'm using to layout the program structure.  So if you have MyCompany.MyProduct.MyModule, then strings in that module would be MyModule_Blah_Blah.  That way they're unique within the overall product.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Name Value Pair in resources like

CloseConfirmation - Do you want to close the window without saving ?

Add a new class called Messages.

```
 public static class Messages
{
    public const String CloseConfirmation = "CloseConfirmation";
    public static String GetMessage( String messageId )
    {
        return //your namespace//.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString( messageId );
    }}
```

and to access it use

```
MessageBox.Show( Messages.GetMessage(Messages.CloseConfirmation));
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This isn't about naming conventions of keys but more about strategies on how to access messages in resource files.

Comment: Thanks Prajeesh, I can access the resource without a problem. My issue though is that I may have several hundred keys, and want an easy way to look them up. I've come across a hoerarchical convention like: Menu.File.Open as an example for a menu caption. I like this approach, but decimals are not premitted when using strongly-typed resources (which I am). Thanks though...