# Localization fails in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, localization

I'm using VS2015 and I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC5 project. In my resources file I have this :

```
Name : Kisi_Gösterecek_Kişi
Value : Gösterecek Kişi
```

In my View, I have this :

```
<th width="45%">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactKisi)</th>
```

As an error, I get this :

> Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.
>   Type 'MyProject.Resources' is not public or does not contain a public static
>   string property with the name 'Kisi_Gösterecek_Kiþi'.

I know that this is some kind of localization error. But I don't know how to solve it. Can you tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Addition to the Answers given, verify the "DisplayAttribute" provided on the ViewModel, e.g.:

```
                                                                 check this
                                                                     ||
                                                                     \/
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(MyProject.Resources), Name = "Kisi_Gosterecek_Kisi")]
public string ContactKisi { get; set; }
```

Verify that the Name provided as string is **exactly matching** the Key in the Resource file, incuding all special characters (you shouldn't use any though), and if you need to, you might want to ensure that the same Encoding of the File is used, e.g. "UTF-8"

Answer (score 2):

You should change Turkish characters in the key of the resource to English characters. Also consider checking out the [key naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896342/resource-resx-file-key-naming-conventions) to prevent further conflicts.

> Kisi_G**o**sterecek_Ki**s**i